# Issue with with 'use strict' and underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, yeoman, underscore.js-templating

I've written an app using Yeoman and backbone.js. At the top of every js file I have specified `'use strict';` and when I run my grunt tasks jshint does not encounter any errors.

I am able to build my app with grunt without issue however when I try to run the uglified js I get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement`

I've searched the code base and the only things using a with statement is underscore.

I'm new to strict mode so I'm not sure how I can resolve this issue. Can I not use strict mode anywhere that I use an underscorejs function?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Given the code samples below (shortened for brevity). How could I change it to resolve this issue.

```
'use strict';

/*global, Backbone, JST*/

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/MyView.ejs'],

    initialize: function()
    {
        this.render();
    },

    render : function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.templateVariables()));
        return this;
    },

    templateVariables: function()
    {
        return {var1 : 'Hello', var2 : 'World'};
    }
});
```

in MyView.ejs

```
<p><%= var1 %><%= var2 %>!</p> //<p>Hello World!</p>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using @mu is too shorts's answer below I discovered that the best way to resolve the calls to _.template that were giving me grief was change my grunt-JST task as follows:

```
jst: {
        compile: {
            options:
            {
                templateSettings:
                {
                    variable: 'data'
                }
            },
            files: {
                '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.ejs']
            }
        }
    },
```

And then change each of my templates to use the `<%= data.templateVariable %>` format.

May not apply to others, but I ran into this issue using Yeoman with Grunt and a Backbone generator so I can't be the only one.

Comment: Are you using precompiled Underscore templates somewhere? The only `with` in Underscore is inside the code that `_.template` generates so no one should even be aware of `with` being used unless they're looking at the compiled template functions that `_.template` produces.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're asking if I'm using under _.template() anywhere? Yes I am. I am assuming then that I need to be more selective with strict mode in that file?

Comment: @mu is too short - I did some more digging. I am using JST templates throughout the application. The precompiled templates.js uses with statements throughout it. So my question then becomes how can I resolve this? If I remove the `use strict;` directives in the view files that have JST templates and then run `grunt --force` and ignore the jshint errors, I still get the same end result with the minified js. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Underscore's `_.template` uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) internally to allow things like `<%= pancakes %>` to be resolved to `obj.pancakes`. If you [look inside `_.template`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.2/underscore.js#L1199), you'll find this:

```
if (!settings.variable) source = 'with(obj||{}){\n' + source + '}\n';
```

That's where the offensive `with` comes from. If you're using JST style precompiled templates, that `source` is what you'll end up with inside your `JST` object and that makes the `with`s visible within the scope of `"use strict"`. Notice that `settings.variable` in there? [The documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) says:

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting. This can significantly improve the speed at which a template is able to render.
>
> ```
> _.template("Using 'with': <%= data.answer %>", {answer: 'no'}, {variable: 'data'});
> => "Using 'with': no"
> ```

So you can suppress the `with`s by using the `variable` option when compiling the templates; of course, this also means that you'll have to rewrite all the `<%= ... %>` parts of your templates to match what the `variable` option has to say (this should also speed up your templates so it might be worth it just for that).

In your case, you'd change the template to this:

```
<p><%= data.var1 %><%= data.var2 %>!</p> //<p>Hello World!</p>
```

and then you'd need to change the `_.template` call that is used to compile the templates to look like this:

```
var compiled_template = _.template(raw_template, null, { variable: 'data' });
```

You don't have to use `data` of course, you just need to use the same thing in both the templates and the `_.template` call.

I don't know how you'd change how your set up calls `_.template` but it shouldn't be that difficult. I suppose you could monkey patch `_.template` to have a default value for `variable` as a last resort.

Here's a simple demo that should illustrate what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Az8QM/

---

Alternatively, if we look at how [`"use strict"` is scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode), we'll see that:

> Strict mode applies to *entire scripts* or to *individual functions*.

So you can localize your strictness with something like this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    // All your non-JST JavaScript goes here.
})();
// Append your JST out here.
```

You could also use two JavaScript files instead of just one:

1. One for your non-template JavaScript with `"use strict"` enabled.
2. A second one with just your `JST`, this one would **not** `"use strict"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for a well thought out answer. I believe that the solution to my problem is in there somewhere, but I am unable to translate what you've said into working code. I have provided a sample above of what I am working with. If you would, please show me how to convert it to a working solution. Ideally I'd like to convert my templates for the performance improvements. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a bit more for the first approach. I tend to use the Rails asset pipeline for this sort of thing so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to solve the _.template calls by altering my grunt task to use the templateSettings options. I've edited my question to show what was needed. Cheers.

Comment: Cool, thanks for filling in the missing bits I didn't know about.