# How to solve "JavaScriptException value = SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode" in HTMLUnit

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, screen-scraping, htmlunit

In my java code, I am trying to harvest a web page using HTMLUnit libraries. My code is simple as follows,

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException
{
        webClient = new WebClient();

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/yyyyyy/");

        System.out.println(page.getTitleText());

        webClient.close();

}
```

However, once I run the code, it produces the following exceptions:

```
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode (https://www.wtatennis.com/resources/v2.1.0/scripts/vendors.min.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:882)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:537)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:762)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1004)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:361)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:234)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:256)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:559)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:513)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1192)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1132)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3185)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2110)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:937)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:443)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:394)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.parse(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:758)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parse(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:236)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parseHtml(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:280)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:163)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:553)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:419)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:488)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
    at htmlunit.WTAHarvester.main(WTAHarvester.java:27)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException: SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode (https://www.wtatennis.com/resources/v2.1.0/scripts/vendors.min.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1009)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:427)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:340)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3607)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:753)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:867)
    ... 34 more
JavaScriptException value = SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode
======= EXCEPTION END ========

Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode (https://www.wtatennis.com/resources/v2.1.0/scripts/vendors.min.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:882)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:537)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:762)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1004)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:361)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:234)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:256)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:559)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:513)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1192)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1132)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3185)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2110)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:937)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:443)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:394)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.parse(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:758)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parse(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:236)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parseHtml(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:280)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:163)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:553)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:419)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:488)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
    at htmlunit.WTAHarvester.main(WTAHarvester.java:27)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException: SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode (https://www.wtatennis.com/resources/v2.1.0/scripts/vendors.min.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1009)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:427)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:340)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3607)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:753)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:867)
    ... 34 more
JavaScriptException value = SyntaxError: with statements not allowed in strict mode
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this file:

https://www.wtatennis.com/resources/v2.1.0/scripts/vendors.min.js#1

That file contains minified libraries, concatenated together. Among these libraries, there is [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/), which uses a `with` statement as you can see in [underscoreJS's source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1589).

But the file it's included in *(first link above)* also has a `"use strict";` statement, which will throw errors when it detects practices it assumes to be unsafe. The `with` statement is one of them. Other people have [had this problem in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679422/issue-with-with-use-strict-and-underscore-js), and it's fixable if they can change their scripts.

That being said, I don't see the error when going to the homepage of that website. But even if I did, I guess you don't have control over the JS which runs on this page. I don't know Java, nor the `WebClient` *class(?)* you're using, but maybe you don't need to execute the page's JS, and are able to [disable scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045951/prevent-htmlunit-2-13-from-executing-javascript)?

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can disable it indeed and the errors are gone in this case but I need Java script to load some html elements that I need to harvest and that's why I need to keep Java script enabled. I don't have control over js because it is not my website. So are you saying there is no solution?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman I don't see a _clean_ way to do it unless you have control over the original website. But again, I don't know Java and this WebClient class. However, if I had to do it myself using other tools, I would probably try to intercept the request to that file, and alter the response to remove the `"use strict";` statement. Not very clean, but could get the job done. Maybe [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728374/1913729) could help with this? **Edit** a comment under that answer suggests that it does not allow accessing the body. Might be a deadend...

Comment: Even dirtier suggestion: instead of altering the body, an alternative could be to alter the headers, by setting the response status to `302 Redirect` and `location` to a URL where you host your own, altered version of the script.